# Windows 7, how to get unlock (Press Ctrl+Alt+del) prompt on all monitors?

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors

I have a laptop that I keep shut in a docking station as I have two screens connected to the laptop and it cannot display to both of those AND its own screen.

However, when my computer locks by itself (Not when I lock it using Ctrl+Alt+Del) the login prompt is ONLY on it screen (at least its there when I open it up) and my primary external monitor is off and my other one is all black.

This means to log in I have to hit Ctrl+Alt+Del and blindly enter my password--which I don't mind *too* much, but would prefer if I could actually see the unlock/login prompt instead of typing on a black screen.

Any way to have it show the login prompt on all monitors?

**EDIT** - based on feedback providing more system specs:

- Laptop is a DELL Latitude E6510
- Video card is a nVidia NVS3100M with driver version 257.29 (didn't see anything in nVidia control panel that would help me)
- Docking Station is Dell ePort Plus
- Two 24" monitors are plugged into the docking station via DVI
- Laptop lid is closed (GPU only supports 2 screens) and power management set to not sleep when plugged in and closed
- One of the monitors is set as the primary display and has taskbar and is where login prompt is shown when locked via Ctrl+Alt+Del; the other has my desktop extended to it

Comment: Must be a graphics setting or a driver issue, my laptop is connected to an external monitor (No dock) and I don't have this issue. You edit your post to include the model of Docking Station and Laptop, maybe someone with a similar setup knows what is going on.

Comment: Do you have any special drivers or third party display software installed?  If you are using Nividia they usually have software which can tweak stuff like this.

Comment: Please provide your system specifications.

Comment: Apologies for not listing detailed system specifications before.  I've updated my question with the information.  No special drivers or software.